# How to return custom error message in Spring Boot for /error page

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, microservices, custom-error-pages

I have a spring boot project and some UI with thymeleaf. I have designed a /error page instead of the White level error, and it is working as expected. However I need to pass some string to /error and display that string in the error page. I am wondering how to do that.

This is my **/error** page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Error Occurred.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}">
</head>

<body>    
    <th:block th:include="/_header"></th:block>
    <th:block th:include="/menu"></th:block>

    <div class="page-title">Error!</div>
    <h3 style="color: red;">Sorry! Something went wrong !</h3>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Error**  method :

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String error() {
    logger.info("Error Page called...");
    return "error";
}
```

Instead of the error message `Sorry! Something went wrong !` I want to send something specific from the caller. How to do that.

Comment: You don't really normally _call_ the error handler. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do? (Note that Spring Boot already has some magic support for providing your own templates; see `BasicErrorController` for the details.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- My basic requirement is whenever the error page is called  due to some failures in some api I want to pass the reason of failure and print it on my page. Just a string. Thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a simple way at last using `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute`.

Here is my some controller method from where I am redirecting the `/error` with reason :

```
String errorMsg = "Cart is Empty. Add some products to Cart." ;
CustomErrorMessage error = new CustomErrorMessage(errorMsg);
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorForm", error);
return "redirect:/error";
```

Ans here is my `error` page :

```
    <div class="page-title">
        <h3 style="color: red">Sorry! Something went wrong !</h3>
        <th:block th:if="${errorForm == null}">
            <h4>Go to Home Page : <a th:href="@{/}">Home</a></h4>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${errorForm != null}">
            <div><ul><li>Error reason : <span th:utext="${errorForm.errorMsg}"></span></li></ul></div>
            <h4>Go to Home Page : <a th:href="@{/}">Home</a></h4>               
        </th:block>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

Template

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Error Occurred.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}">
</head>

<body>    
    <th:block th:include="/_header"></th:block>
    <th:block th:include="/menu"></th:block>

    <div class="page-title">Error!</div>
    <h3 style="color: red;" th:text="${errorMsg}">Sorry! Something went wrong !</h3>    
</body>
</html>



//  Controller
 @RequestMapping("/error")
public String error() {
    logger.info("Error Page called...");
    mmodel.addAttribute("errorMsg", "Custom Error Message");
    return "error";

}
```